# Interface in Mvc Project, Implementing in Data Project - circular reference?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an mvc application just to practice some best practices (trying to do everything the 'correct' way). To be more precise, I thought of building an MVC Application with some ajax endpoints for a chat service.

I wanted to have that one a little more flexible, so I thought of using `interfaces` to define the structure of used objects. Those interfaces should then be implemented by the DataLayer Project.

Now I wanted to define those interfaces in the Mvc-Project and put the datalayer stuff in a separate project. This would lead to a circular reference though, which I thought of as bad practice.

What is the 'correct' way to solve this issue? Is my approach reasonable?

Some code to show what I want to archive:

Mvc Project:

```
public interface IChatUser
{
    Guid    UserID  { get; }
    string  Name    { get; }
}
```

Datalayer Project (part of class):

```
public class User : IChatUser
{
    private Guid _userID;
    public  Guid UserID
    {
        get
        {
            return _userID;
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.LastName + " ," + this.FirstName;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you aren't just using NHibernate?  If you are then your controllers just have access to a Session object for any basic queries you want to run.

Complex stuff gets broken out into separate query or command objects.

We built a full MVC app using the stuff discussed here: http://ayende.com/blog/154081/limit-your-abstractions-you-only-get-six-to-a-dozen-in-the-entire-app and were very happy with the results.

Comment: thanks for the link, i'm gonna have a look at it when i got some more time :) +1 for now!